# Search in field that contain values like set (56,76,45)

Tags: mysql

I have a field (name is ShareWith) that has values like this 
**56,76,45**
These values for each record is different.
But I want to find record that contain these values and my query is :
**`select * from table where 76 in (ShareWith)`**
but it can not find 
Is there any solution for finding values without separate select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store data as comma separated string and instead normalize it to one to many, however in this case you can use `find_in_set()` as

```
select * from table where find_in_set(76,ShareWith) > 0
```

Comment: great @Abhik we dont see these things in learning materials , what best resource for intermediate or advance set you can recommend for mysql

Comment: @A.B well there are several docs across the web about the normalization. The rule thumb is when you are saving some relational data you should avoid storing them as comma separation. the non related data which are not part of any relation ex: Some users feed data containing several information could be stored as above so that its just used to display them not doing any query logic.